# Negation of a set

Tags: logic

The question is: 
Let S be a set, R be a binary relation on S, and x an element of S. Express in English the negation of the statement “For all x in S, xRx”.

I was originally thinking since the negation is just the opposite, I would switch S and R to get an expression of "For all x in R, xSx"

Comment: A good way to start is by negating the statement in a way that always works: “It is not the case that for all x in S, xRx.”

Comment: which point on a circle is "just the opposite" from the center?

Answer (score 0):

"There exists an $x$ in $S$ such that $(x,x) \not\in R$ "

Comment: Why change the way we're writing relations? Just write "such that $\lnot(xRx)$."

Answer (score 0):

I would go with:

"There exists an element $x$ in the set $S$, such that $x$ is not related to itself under $R$."